# access class variables with brackets around the key

Tags: php

So I have this output from var_dump($object)

```
object(MyObject\Long\Namespace\User)[167]
  public 'role' => string 'customer' (length=8)
  public '[repository]' => string 'MyStringStuff.Users' (length=21)
```

but I can't seem to get to the 'repository' string.  I've tried...

```
var_dump($object->role); // this works and gives me 'customer'

var_dump($object->{repository}; // gives me a undefined constant

var_dump($object->{'repository'}; // gives me null

var_dump($object->{$repository}; // gives me undefined variable

var_dump($object->{'[repository]'}); // gives me null

$repo = 'repository';
var_dump($object->{$repo}); // give me null
```

How the heck do I get the string 'MyStringStuff.Users' out of that?

Here's a screen shot : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/9152cdc2-e6f4-45d6-b415-c55ea9a61349/5f44156aa06c5e3c7be66b4b97d90161

Comment: That doesn't look exactly like `var_dump` output.

Comment: Here's a screen shot : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/2d6deba0-5689-4847-91e2-9ab7ab7cc725/990942e410299ab7d2a8b2fbac646930

Comment: The screen dump references an array, what's happened to the Long\Namespace\User object?

Comment: It looks like an XDebug var_dump...

Comment: Here's a bigger screen shot : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/9152cdc2-e6f4-45d6-b415-c55ea9a61349/5f44156aa06c5e3c7be66b4b97d90161

Comment: Your last attempt should work https://3v4l.org/qXpeY

Comment: yeah it "should", but that of course is why I'm asking a question on stackoverflow that has been asked numerous times before, but for some reason is still not working for me... very odd

Comment: Maybe there are hidden characters in the property name. This is not unusual. Use get_object_vars and check the key.

Comment: is_object() returns true, get_object_vars() returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can try typecasting your object as an array and just using the named key:

```
$event = (array) $event->subject()->entity;
$repo = $event['[repository]'];
```

However, that last one you try should work properly.

Comment: Well here's what I get from that : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/029a6a92-b94e-4f64-a1b5-ec7bf9ffac4c/336ea836c4ccd6d7d2f89fcc060269c1